# How to solve FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) Cannot use [] for reading?

Tags: php, database, laravel, codeigniter, web

whenever i want to view a profile it showing me a fatal error, with the message

> FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
>   Cannot use [] for reading

why it is happening

```
@if($user->is_employer() || $user->is_agent())
                <div class="profile-company-logo mb-3">
                    <img src="{{ $user->logo_url[] }}" class="img-fluid" style="max-width: 100px;" />
                </div>
            @endif

            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-4">

                <tr>
                    <th>@lang('app.name')</th>
                    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>@lang('app.email')</th>
                    <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>@lang('app.gender')</th>
                    <td>{{ ucfirst($user->gender) }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>@lang('app.phone')</th>
                    <td>{{ $user->phone }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>@lang('app.address')</th>
                    <td>{{ $user->address }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>@lang('app.country')</th>
                    <td>
                        @if($user->country)
                            {{ $user->country->name }}
                        @endif
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>@lang('app.created_at')</th>
                    <td>{{ $user->signed_up_datetime() }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>@lang('app.status')</th>
                    <td>{{ $user->status_context() }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>




            @if($user->is_employer() || $user->is_agent())
                    <h3 class="mb-4">About Company</h3>

                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>@lang('app.state')</th>
                        <td>{{ $user->state_name }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>@lang('app.city')</th>
                        <td>{{ $user->city }}</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <th>@lang('app.website')</th>
                        <td>{{ $user->website }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>@lang('app.company')</th>
                        <td>{{ $user->company }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>@lang('app.company_size')</th>
                        <td>{{company_size($user->company_size)}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>@lang('app.about_company')</th>
                        <td>{{ $user->about_company }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>@lang('app.premium_jobs_balance')</th>
                        <td>{{ $user->premium_jobs_balance }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            @endif


            @if( ! empty($is_user_id_view))
                <a href="{{route('users_edit', $user->id )}}">
                    <i class="la la-pencil-square-o"></i> @lang('app.edit') </a>
            @else
                <a href="{{ route('profile_edit') }}"><i class="la la-pencil-square-o"></i> @lang('app.edit') </a>
            @endif
```

i want to view the profile and edit after i click the edit button.

Comment: `logo_url[]` - any typo in this??

Comment: Why are you using `[]` in there?

Comment: ok it worked for user but , still showing "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given" this for  employer.

Comment: Where is the `htmlspecialchars` usage? The message should tell you everything you need to know, `expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`. You have an array there, not a string. The function works on a string.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` is run everytime `{{ $... }}` is called; it's part of the `blade` templating engine. Essentially, something in `{{ }}` is an `array` and not a `string`, so you'll need to loop that variable in order to use it. Like `{{ $user->logo_url[] }}`?

Comment: Mr. Lewis can you please fix it for me, i am getting frustrated it took my 2 hrs already.

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't make sense:

```
if ($user->is_employer() || $user->is_agent()) logo_url[]
```

If the condition is true, you're running:

```
logo_url[]
```

Which is a syntax error. It appears to be a typo and you probably just want this:

```
if ($user->is_employer() || $user->is_agent())
```

Comment: after removing the [ ] from logo_url , it showing me "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given" this for employer.

Comment: @user3783243 Ha strange, it was rendering that way before your edit, but I was too lazy to actually go fix it.